all pairs shortes path variant
Let $G=(V,E) $ a directed Graph with a coloring function $F:E \to red,blue$ and a weight function $W: E \to R$
I need to find all pairs shortest path s.t. every path visits at least one red edge, or informs that there's no path to from u to v that satisfies this demand.
I tried to run Johnson's algorithm on a graph with duplicated nodes, each red node passes from the "Original" copy to the duplicated, yet I'm not sure this has the best complexity or that it yields the correct output.
